# Getting error "dependency is not satisfiable libpng12-0" while installing TeamViewer

Tags: software-installation, teamviewer

[image]

I am trying to install **TeamViewer** but I'm getting this error:

```
dependency is not satisfiable libpng12-0
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: It would be "nice" to respond to people who answer your questions, you know..

Answer (score 0):

> libpng is a library implementing an interface for reading and writing
>   PNG (Portable Network Graphics) format files.
>
> This package contains the runtime library files needed to run software
>   using libpng.

If you search in Synaptic you can install it and then install teamviewer, not sure what version do you have tho!

Answer (score 0):

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download , Download the package and install it . Dependency problem will be over .